# Why does Windows Firewall ignore a rule targeting specific application?

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall

After creating a rule targeting specific application, nothing changed as if my new rule was just ignored.

That is if my rule says to allow, but default is to block, application is still blocked. Should I disable Windows Firewall completely, the application in question could establish connection.

Answer (score 0):

While specifying new rule's application path, Windows Firewall tries to substitute parts of the path with environmental variables like `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` etc.

That's nice, but eventually it may come up with `%USERPROFILE%`, which might be confusing for a system service, not running with any particular user credentials, but system. Try and find yourself that very application starting with system folder or drive root or whatever! That's the case for Windows Firewall which could not find any application to apply rule to and as such no rule applied after all.

Try to avoid using environmental variables by specifying path directly.

Comment: Care to explain, Mr/Mrs Downvoter?

Comment: This saved helped me figure out why my firewall rule was being ignored! Thanks!

Comment: @CameronTinker Same happened to me! Hence this question and answer!